# Ошибка в реализации длинной арифметики

Tags: c++, длинная-арифметика

Я скопировал с e-maxx'а и объединил всё в одну программу: http://pastebin.com/Wxw7PvMc
Программа при входных данных: 123456789 1000
выдаёт: (сумму, разность, произведение, частное)
123457789
123456789
12345678900
12345678

Проблема в том, что она делит и умножает только на b (второе число) <= 100. Т.е. при b = 10^3 или b = 10^6 она всё равно умножает и делит на 100. Если b <= 100, то она умножает на b.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А у вас совсем-совсем нет отладчика?

Comment: >А у вас совсем-совсем нет отладчика?

наверное, это не путь самурая

Comment: @122, просто не все целые числа можно представить в типе **`int`**.


    /* Minimum and maximum values a `signed int' can hold.  */
    #  define INT_MIN (-INT_MAX - 1)
    #  define INT_MAX 2147483647


Когда Вы умножаете свое `123456789` на что-то больше 173 результат не влезает в 32-бита int-а (возникает переполнение), что и ставит Вас в тупик. 

Почему у Вас так получается с усечением до 100 - если честно, просто неохота разбираться с Вашим кодом (может кто другой подскажет).

Попробуйте сменить у переменных тип `int` на `long long` (ну, и почитайте что-нибудь, соответственно, о типах)

Comment: @avp, спасибо за ответ, но, по-моему, т.к. проблема в реализации длинной арифметики, там всё не так просто. Я храню цифры в векторы, умножаю на каждую цифру b (школьный алгоритм умножения в столбик). Т.е. там не просто int*int - переполнение.

Comment: оригинал, если что: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer

Comment: @122, так бы сразу и написали, что реализуете арифметику с  числами произвольной длины.

Я не являюсь спецом в этой области, но мне кажется, что промежуточные вычисления (с числами в середине вектора, где `carry` считаете) надо проводить  unsigned.

--

По поводу второй ссылки - Вы уверены, что у них все правильно работает?

Comment: А зачем брать каждую 9ю цифру и проделывать с ней странные манипуляции? Может все таки брать все подряд, хотя бы в рамках эксперимента? И возьмите таки отладчик, а код в функции main лучше сразу выбросить и написать нормальный.